# JQuery Validator, remote rule with GET instead of POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to do a remote validation with JQuery Validator:

```
rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 12,
            remote: {
                url: '/users/register/isUserAvailable',
                dataType: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'username': $('#username').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    // success tasks...
                }

            }
        },
```

I want to see if there is a way to do the validation with GET instead of POST to have it like this:

```
rules: {
            username: {
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12,
                remote: {
                    url: function(){
                        var username = $('#username').val();
                        return '/users/register/isUserAvailable/' + username,
                    } 
                    dataType: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        // success tasks...
                    }

                }
            },
```

NOTE: I know post is secure & is currently working fine, but I was just wondering if this was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few syntax problems in your examples

1. to change from GET to POST the parameter name is ***type***, not
   *dataType*
2. the ***url*** parameter is not evaluated as a function, it is a string.  This would explain why you are getting weird characters, they are the text of your function urlencoded.

Two more points though

1. The default is of the remote method is GET, so you don't need specify the type for GET
2. Be careful overriding ***success*** in the remote method, unless you know the workings of the success callback of the remote method don't do it.

[from the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method) keep it simple like so

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      remote: {
        url: "check-email.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          username: function() {
            return $( "#username" ).val();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there is no restriction for that but you need to change `dataType: 'GET'` for `type: 'GET'`

Comment: is not working either, this is what is being sent in the query string:
%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(username);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20'/users/register/isUserAvailable/';%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D?username=emanuele

Comment: Maybe the url does not allow to work as a function but instead as a variable only.

Comment: @Uuid: I believe that `type` is not the problem and `GET` is allowed. Check if you can specify `data` attribute for your remote definition.

Comment: It does allow to specify the method without any problem but what is weird is that whenever I try to return the url inside the function throws the above. %20...

Answer (score 1):

Your remote syntax is incorrect, there is no success , the remote only expects a boolean value based on your supplied data

```
remote: {
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/users/register/isUserAvailable',
     data: {
      username: function() {
        return $( "#username" ).val();
      }
            }//end remote
```